# Using jmeter as an automation tool to submit data to site

Tags: java, jmeter

Im trying to submit data to a site that has no api using `cURL`. Ive been battling with some javascript encrypted `POST` data for the past couple of weeks to no avail, some one recommended i look at Jmeter (the load balancing tool) to bypass it by letting Jmeter feed the values to the site.

Im not quite sure how this would work, or indeed if it would at all, but is this a viable route to go down ?

Comment: No, JMeter won't make it any easier than using curl. Why don't you post a question about the difficulties you're having with curl?

Comment: Please give a scenario you want JMeter script to follow

Answer (score 1):

You might also try using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). 
You can [record actions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) done on a site and then replay them.

Comment: Thanks @rzymek - Ive tried Selenium and the Selenium RC server and although i can get it to work, its quite fragile and also takes a long time to complete c.45 seconds as its has to wait for things to load, scroll down the pages (which have continuous loading ajax content ect) so in this instance its not that great an approach, but thanks for the input.

Comment: Also just a note on the Selenium IDE in my experience although it can be handy as a click and record macro type setup, due to the way most html is set out (ie. not everything has unique ids or classes) you have to revert to using xpath to actually locate the items you need.

Comment: Well, you did not mention how much data you want to submit :)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is an amazing tool! Here is a link to get you started: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/topics/10018-jmeter-tutorials

Comment: Thanks, im going to have a look through those now - In regards to the question do you know how Jmeter would be used in this scenario to bypass the encrypted post data.

Comment: With JMeter you can record the HTTP requests from your browser and play them back as a load test. You can use JMeter's built in proxy (I think it's called HTTP recorder in 2.10) though personally I prefer to use BlazeMeter's Chrome Extension which saves your chrome browsing as a Jmeter script.
Is each request dynamically generated or are you just having difficulty capturing the HTTP requests into a JMeter script?
Can you share the URL you are trying to load test?

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem is not quite rich enough to fully understand what it is you are looking to do. If you are looking to do HTTP posts as you suggest, maybe [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) will be a more appropriate tool to use.

Answer (score -1):

jmeter with a data file can keep repeat the same request a lot of time , so if what you want is just change some of the params then jmeter will be ok.